# How to uninstall Gnome from Ubuntu Mate

Tags: gnome, uninstall, mate

I use Ubuntu Mate. I love it it works perfectly for me. But recently I installed Gnome to run alongside it. I tried Gnome But I don't like it at all! It's alot more complicated than it needs to be. All that aside though because I wanna know how to uninstall Gnome. I want all of it's files and the option to launch it when I start up my computer GONE!

Comment: How did you install GNOME?

Comment: Through a live CD

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand it correctly, you have Ubuntu GNOME in a separate partition. In that case, I think this is what you need to do:

1. Open *Disks* (terminal command: `gnome-disks`) and delete the partition.
2. Run `sudo update-grub`

But please be careful. There are always inherent risks when playing with partitions. Please backup any valuable content.